# How to set an alternate JsonSerializer to apply to all returns of a specific @Controller class in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, jsonserializer

Say I have a default way to serialize Foo objects. How can I set a specific @Controller class to use an alternate JsonSerializer for Foo objects?

With @JsonSerialize inside Foo I can only specify one universal behavior for all serializations of it. How can I have alternate ones?

Answer (score 0):

What about using [@JsonView](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)'s?

With a help of, it is possible dynamically describe the serialization/deserialization of objects, so it is possible to choose, on a per handler method basis, which field should be (and how) serialized.

Here is a good [article](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) from Spring with example.

Comment: Unfortunately @JsonView can't be applied to a class. So I'd need to add it to every method in my controller. In fact my controller extends another, so I'll be forced to override every method from the "super" controller :/